# How can I Compact Code

Tags: swift, swift2

I have multiple text fields in my app and want all of them  to not crash if the textfield is empty.

I have the code that fixes this but I am wondering if there is something i can write that shortcuts this code?

SO i could write

```
fixNilError()
```

and it would run the code:

```
if textField.text != nil {
   print("Success")
}
```

Comment: Put your textFields in an array then use a loop.

Comment: If you have a default in mind such as `""` when a textField is `nil`, just use the nil coalescing operator `??` when reading them to safely unwrap.  For example, `let text1 = textField1.text ?? ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textField.text returns an optional value, which means that the value is either something, or nil.
To handle this value, you need to "unwrap" it, and one of the cleaner way to make it would be this one:

```
if let fieldText = textField.text {
 print(fieldText)
 }
```

Not sure it helps you to make your code shorter, but optionals is a clever way to make it secure.

Answer (score 1):

use method `hasText()` to check multiple `textfield` empty or not see below code and code accordingly.

```
if !text1 .hasText(){      // in this case text1 does not contain text
    // deliver appropriate message to user here
    return;
}else if !text2 .hasText(){
    // deliver appropriate message to user here
    return;
}
```